# Latin statement from a benefactor

Tags: idiom, word-request

What would be a Latin expression to state that something was given by a benefactor (i.e. not simply a gift from a friend or relative)?

I would be attempting to describe the situation of one person giving something of value to another person for their advantage because the recipient would be unlikely to obtain the valuable item on their own. In that regard, do/dare/dedi/datus would be likely be too generic of a concept.

Benefactor and similar terms are Latinate, but do they have the same connotation/usage in Latin? i.e. would "benefactum a *Nomine*" be good Latin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Donare* seems like a pretty good fit. [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddono): "To give one something as a present; to present, bestow; to grant, vouchsafe, confer ... to present one with any thing".